# monodevelop and nunit integration

Tags: exception, nunit, integration, monodevelop

I use MonoDevelop from several years but I'm now having problem with NUnit plugin.

I've started a new simple project with few tests... The binary is tested without problem from nunit-console, but when in MonoDevelop I get a NullReferenceException and the stack trace reports an error at System.Runtime.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke etc.

I'm running Ubuntu 11.10 with a 64 bit processor. I've no problem on Windows (how it's possible?) or Mac laptops (this is normal!).

Regards,
Giacomo

Comment: Hi,
have you found any reason? I have the same problem here on my Ubuntu 11.10 amd64.

Comment: I'm running tests with `nunit-console myassemblynet.dll` for now. No reason found! Maybe a **monodevelop** bug? Should we notify IDE developers of the problem?

Comment: I think that the problem lays on _11.10_ of ubuntu... I'm not using it anymore. I use **11.04** disabling Unity and everything works fine! I hope this can help you... Regards, Giacomo

Comment: I opened a bug report on launchpad (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/monodevelop/+bug/889241) some time ago. But no answer so far.
I think it's a bug in the ubuntu-package not monodevelop itself.

Comment: Same problem guys, I'll throw a word in if I fix something

Comment: I think the problem is that Oneiric try to bundle MonoDevelop with nunit 2.5.
If you can life with nunit 2.4.8 then try to install the latest MonoDevelop from https://launchpad.net/~keks9n/+archive/monodevelop-latest